# GCM message not pushed to phone

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-cloud-messaging

For the past few days I have been digging around to try and get a POC phonegap app working
I am using PushPlugin from phonegap
My apk is being built via the build.phonegap.com service

The code below connects to GCM and generates a message ID
but the device actually never gets the push notification

What am I missing?

```
    Dim regID As String = "APA91bHQX1wnaRjU_Sq_vIiUOjpHxAr3N3Y0XKwWS3SpowFA6iC73eqNRAsyb_9Z_NorhDpVpBXkLzzq94YWE0tRr9vY8gdEtJvxfVi9sF3xH09UvTvT9Heu_lTzhzEa1IO0i74KijNBaVgYjqrEXZDab9sCTclYxA"
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "key=AIzaSyCU80wS2pUy_6HGM6gJ4JTUdqGH9NhNa2M")
    request.Headers.Add("Sender: id=924375227132")
    Dim collapsKey = Guid.NewGuid.ToString("N")
    Dim postdata As String = "" & _
        "delay_while_idle=false" & _
        "&time_to_live=108" & _
        "&delay_while_idle=1" & _
        "&collapse_key=" & collapsKey & "" & _
        "&data.payload.msgcnt=3" & _
        "&data.payload.message=Welcome to this app" & _
        "&registration_id=" & regID
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata)
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim resposne As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
    Dim dataresponse As Stream = resposne.GetResponseStream
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataresponse)
    Dim sResponseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    Console.WriteLine(sResponseFromServer)
    reader.Close()
    dataresponse.Close()
    resposne.Close()
```

Phonegap HTML code

```
        var pushNotification;
        function RegisterDeviceABCD()
        {
            try
            {
                alert("Here");
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' )
                {
                    pushNotification.register(
                        successHandler,
                        errorHandler, {
                            "senderID":"924375227132",
                            "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    pushNotification.register(
                        tokenHandler,
                        errorHandler, {
                            "badge":"true",
                            "sound":"true",
                            "alert":"true",
                            "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
                        });
                }
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please include your client code and manifest

Comment: I could not post the whole thing on this message so updated the question. The issue is that the notification is not showing up on the device even when it is saying it registered :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my request to JSON and it seemed to work

```
Dim postdata As String = ""
                postdata &= " { " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= "   ""collapse_key"": """ & collapsKey & """, " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= "   ""time_to_live"": 108, " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= "   ""delay_while_idle"": true, " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= "   ""data"": { " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= "       ""msgcnt"": ""3"", " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= "       ""message"": ""Welcome to this app"" " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= "   }, " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= "   ""registration_ids"":[" & vbCrLf & regID & vbCrLf & "] " & vbCrLf
                postdata &= " } "
```

Also changed the content type on the request to application/json